# Change the behaviour in Spring Cloud Stream. Make header matcher case sensitive

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I need my custom 'Id' kafka header and don't want the 'id' header from the Spring Kafka Streams.

**protected static class SimplePatternBasedHeaderMatcher** uses **toLowerCase()** logic in **public boolean matchHeader** method.

So in the end I got both headers: 'Id' (my header) and 'id' (provided by Spring Cloud Stream).

How to override this behaviour via yaml properties if I don't need caseInsensitive header matcher ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it just in YAML, you would have to create a custom header mapper bean and provide it's name in the YAML.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_binder_properties

> `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.headerMapperBeanName`

> The bean name of a `KafkaHeaderMapper` used for mapping `spring-messaging` headers to and from Kafka headers.

Comment: I see. Looks reasonable for me. Will try to follow this. 
Thanks a lot, @Gary Russell!

Comment: That said, it is not clear what the problem is. The `id` header is never mapped on outbound, and the patterns are only used there. On inbound, `id` and `timestamp` are always changed when a message is mutated. They are an inherent feature of spring-messaging and always present.

Comment: The problem was the following. 
My producer's headers contained both 'id' which was provided as a result of configuring the  **DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper** bean like this:
`DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper("SystemTime", "AppId", "Id"...)`
and my 'Id' header which was put to the **producerKafkaHeaders** like this:

Message<SpecificRecordBase> message = MessageBuilder
        .withPayload(abstractMessage)
        .copyHeaders(producerKafkaHeaders)
        .build();
So in the end producer Headers contained both: 'id' and 'Id' which was pretty strange for me.

Comment: So finally changing the bean from **DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper** to the **SimpleKafkaHeaderMapper** with the same bean configuration solved my problem.